# Apache Struts 2 namespace Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (S2-057)

Tags: java

I have updated my application to struts 2.5.17 and removed the reference of the previous Struts version from the JSP pages and added JSTL tag libraries. I am still getting severity 4 vulnerability in vulnerability scan.